# How to wrap an object change in my own transaction and incorporate it with Hibernate to JTA?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, transactions, jta

I have a web-app, which I deploy on Tomcat 6 and it uses Hibernate.
It receives messages on a JMS queue which trigger changes both to my DB, via Hibernate and to an Object of mine (`Agent`).
The web-requests also access the DB, via Hibernate, and access the shared object (there's a `ConcurrentHashMap<AgentId,Agent>` held by a singleton).
My problem is that I have a JMS message which changes several different `Agent`s and several tables and I need the changes in the `Agent`s to be available if and only if the DB transaction completed successfully. In addition I do not want to employ read locks as that is too much of a performance hazard for me.
I was thinking of **somehow** implementing the `XAResource` interface for my singleton and then use JTA to manage both my singleton and my Hibernate transaction.
What do you think? Does it sound reasonable? Am I way off?

If any additional details are needed please don't hesitate to ask
Ittai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of implementing `XAResource`, you could use a transactional cache like EHCache which supports JTA since 2.0 (i.e. it can act as an XA resource and participate in a XA transaction alongside other XA resources).

Comment: do you mean I should just have the EHCache maintain the above mentioned map?

Comment: I have a performance concern regarding this solution which I posted about (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967111/how-does-ehcache-implement-its-transactions). I'd appreciate it I could receive your input.