# How does EHCache implement its transactions?

Tags: java, performance, transactions, ehcache

The question might sound vague but I'm trying to understand the general concept of the EHCache transaction ability.
Assuming I configure EHCache as a memory cache and I also configure it to cache a `MyObject`.
Does EHCache clone the instance of `MyObject` I'm retrieving if this is done as a part of a transaction?

I'm mainly asking because I was advised (in the answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966346/how-to-wrap-an-object-change-in-my-own-transaction-and-incorporate-it-with-hibern)) to use EHCache and I'm worried about its performance impact. `MyObject` is a medium-weight object and I'd rather not duplicate it unneccesarily.
Also, just to verify, EHCache only blocks writing to the object while in transaction, right?

Thanks,
Ittai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following part of the documentation about the [JTA](http://ehcache.org/documentation/jta.html) support answers most of your questions:

> ### Using a JTA Cache
>
> #### All or nothing
>
> If a cache is enabled for JTA all
>   operations on it must happen within a
>   transaction context, otherwise a
>   `TransactionRequiredException` will be
>   thrown.
>
> #### Change Visibility
>
> The isolation level offered in Ehcache
>   JTA is `READ_COMMITTED`. Ehcache is an
>   `XAResource`. Full two-phase commit is
>   supported.
>
> Specifically:
>
> - **All mutating changes to the cache are transactional** including `put`,
>     `remove`, `putWithWriter`,
>     `removeWithWriter` and `removeAll`.
> - Mutating changes are not visible in the local JVM to or across the cluster
>     until `COMMIT` has been called.
> - Until then, read such as by `cache.get(...)` by other transactions
>     will return the old copy. **Reads do not
>     block**.
>
> #### Write-behind and Write-through
>
> If your XA enabled cache is being used
>   with a writer, write operations will
>   be queued until transaction commit
>   time. Solely a Write-through approach
>   would have its potential XAResource
>   participate in the same transaction.
>   Write-behind, while supported, should
>   probably not be used with an XA
>   transactional Cache, as the operations
>   would never be part of the same
>   transaction. Your writer would also be
>   responsible for obtaining a new
>   transaction...
>
> Using Write-through with a non XA
>   resource would also work, but there is
>   no guarantee the transaction will
>   succeed after the write operation have
>   been executed successfully. On the
>   other hand, any thrown exception
>   during these write operations would
>   cause the transaction to be rolled
>   back by having
>   `UserTransaction.commit()` throw a
>   `RollbackException`.

Regarding performances, I wouldn't worry too much unless your object weights hundreds MB. But if this is really a concern, measure things (as always).

Comment: I guess how EHCache exactly does it falls under the category of "Not my core business", which is why I outsource it, and so this is the best answer available. Thanks.

Comment: @Ittai Well, I definitely tend to agree with that, which is also why I initially suggested using an existing solution. Just in case you want to go lower, the sources are available :)